# Error while publishing message from .NET (WebORB)

Tags: publish, weborb

I am trying to publish message (C# console app):

```
var client = new WeborbClient("http://localhost:57433/weborb.aspx", "MyDestination");
client.Publish("test message");
```

...and getting `NullReferenceException`:

> at Weborb.Writer.ObjectWriter.write(Object obj, IProtocolFormatter writer)
>      at Weborb.Writer.ObjectReferenceWriter.write(Object obj, IProtocolFormatter formatter)
>      at Weborb.Writer.ArrayWriter.write(Object obj, IProtocolFormatter writer)
>      at Weborb.Writer.ArrayReferenceWriter.write(Object obj, IProtocolFormatter formatter)
>      at Weborb.Writer.MessageWriter.writeObject(Object obj, IProtocolFormatter formatter)
>      at Weborb.Writer.AMFBodyWriter.write(Object obj, IProtocolFormatter writer)
>      at Weborb.Writer.MessageWriter.writeObject(Object obj, IProtocolFormatter formatter)
>      at Weborb.Util.Cache.Cache.WriteAndSave(Object obj, IProtocolFormatter formatter)
>      at Weborb.Writer.AMFMessageWriter.write(Object obj, IProtocolFormatter writer)
>      at Weborb.Writer.MessageWriter.writeObject(Object obj, IProtocolFormatter formatter)
>      at Weborb.Util.AMFSerializer.SerializeToBytes(Object obj, Int32 serializationType)
>      at Weborb.Util.AMFSerializer.SerializeToBytes(Object obj)
>      at Weborb.Client.HttpEngine.CreateRequest(V3Message v3Msg, Dictionary`2 headers)
>      at Weborb.Client.HttpEngine.CreateRequest(V3Message v3Msg)
>      at Weborb.Client.HttpEngine.SendRequest[T](V3Message v3Msg, Responder`1 responder, Boolean isSubscription)
>      at Weborb.Client.Engine.SendRequest[T](V3Message v3Msg, Responder`1 responder)
>      at Weborb.Client.WeborbClient.Publish(Object message, Dictionary`2 headers, String subtopic, PublishingResponder responder)
>      at Weborb.Client.WeborbClient.Publish(Object message, Dictionary`2 headers)

Publishing to the same destination works successfully from Flex app:

```
<mx:ChannelSet id="channelSet">
    <mx:AMFChannel url="http://localhost:57433/weborb.aspx"/>     
</mx:ChannelSet>

<mx:Producer id="producer"
         channelSet="{channelSet}"
     destination="MyDestination" />

// ...
var message:AsyncMessage = new AsyncMessage( "weborb messaging is cool" );
producer.send( message );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to deploy weborb.config into the same folder where your executable runs from.